# Automatically edit a php table

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a coins table in phpMyAdmin and I need it to be automatically updated when a user completes a purchase via PayPal. The way it is setup is that PayPal will automatically redirect them to a link I choose.

So, how can I run a script that takes the parameters from the URL and adds a new record to the table?

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help

Answer (score 0):

So that link would need to be a page called something like payment_success.php

On that page you would need to have a script that looks like this:

```
<?php
include 'credentials.php'; /*this is a file that will contain your database connection info

Then here you will establish the connection and enter the data into the desired table*/

$var1 = 'some information collected from paypal that you want to update';
$id = 'some identifiable information about your user that can connect them to the correct row in your table';

I won't hold your hand through all this but the SQL query you would need would be:

UPDATE table_name SET column_1 = '$var1' WHERE ID = '$id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the confirmation PayPal link to increment the number of coins value in the MySQL table for the particular user....!!!

I hope that will work out..... If I could get a idea of your table or some more info, I could give you a clear idea about that.